# How do I make my entire app run in the background?

Tags: android, android-service

I made an app that is just a simple counter that will keep track of a user's strokes as they play golf and save their score while doing it.  I simply want the app to not be killed when the user exits out.  I just want it to run in the background.  So the user can re-enter the program after doing other things, (like texting or checking email)

I understand I need to use services but while trying to research the topic on the web and in other forums, it seems that they all explain how to have a specific activity in the app to continue, not the entire app.

How might I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just store their score and retrieve it when the app restarts?

Comment: sure I was thinking of that but I just don't know how, I am very new to android development.  So I can make an activity that saves their score and runs in the background with the services class?

Comment: What do you mean by "not be killed when the user exits out"? You do realize that Android manages the lifecycle of your app and there is no guarantee that it will not be killed if OS decides so? The same is true for services.

Comment: True, I guess I dont need the whole app to run in the background, I just want a way to save the users score so they can leave and re-enter the app at will.  Without it reseting their score everytime.  Which is what happens right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
  @Override
  protected void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YourOwnPickedName", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("score", the_users_score);
  }
```

and get the score back by doing

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YourOwnPickedName", 0);
    the_users_score = settings.getString("score", "0");
  }
```

Comment: ok i see where your going with this and I like the idea.  I am still a little confused but its my fault because I didn't explain my program well enough.  I basically have an Array of "hole" objects that contains the number of the hole and the number of strokes that were done on that hole.  So I would need a way to refill that array.

Comment: I'd be tempted to stick it in a SQLite database, but there's nothing stopping you, eg, writing that data to a string like "hole1=strokes1;hole2=strokes2;etc. etc.", storing that, and then parsing that string back into an array on restore (using String.split() and also converting the strokes back to integers if necessary.)

Comment: right I actually thought of that a few min after I posted my comment lol,but thanks for all your help I never knew how to save information onto the phone from an app

Comment: So I have been working on your solution and I have another question but this time more general. When you press the back arrow button on an android phone, does that always kill the app and does an app implement onPause() before it is killed? Because I have been trying to implement your strategy to my problem and I have been testing with pressing the back arrow button and I still cant seem to save the users data

Answer (score 0):

You should just store data to permanent storage instead of trying to keep the app alive indefinitely (which can not be 100% achieved anyway):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that Ben Williams was mostly correct, but he missed a step (**editor.commit();**) in the save file. The data does not get stored in the settings file until it is committed:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
  {
     super.onPause();

     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YourOwnPickedName", 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("score", the_users_score);
     editor.commit();
  }
```

I suggest looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html to see the lifecycle (to know exactly where you want to put it for what situation).

Answer (score -1):

You can make it as a windows service application.

Comment: What part of "Android" do you not understand?